# Does the UK have laws that would prevent bringing pets to work (with permission)?

Tags: professionalism, united-kingdom

Are there any laws in the UK which could prevent an employee from bringing their well-behaved dog to work with them, and just have it sit or lie down near your desk out of the way?  *For the sake of this question assume that management and all staff are happy with this.*

I live and work in the UK, and can only find things relating to the USA.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - Bear in mind that the document you linked to seems to be specific to a Ministry of Defence site.  The second paragraph in there, however, does refer to the overriding Health and Safety Act.

Comment: Law SE isn't definitive.  HR would have the correct answer and compliance with their guidelines would protect Terry from any adversity.

Comment: This is a question about *what the law is* in a locale, not a question about a specific company's policies or a request for legal advice.  I don't see why this is off-topic.

Comment: @Monica While I most certainly agree with that and have voted to reopen the question, I also found it interesting that the OP himself voted to close it.

Comment: If you feel it fits then I'm happy to have it open. I just didn't want it to be in the wrong place.

Comment: How is "Are there any laws in the UK which could prevent" not legal advice?   It is not just *what the law is*.  *Could prevent* is a legal opinion.   There will be for than one law and more than one legal opinion.   If it was a simple as the written law(s) we would not have courts handing down decisions on written law(s).

Comment: For an office type environment it seems there are no specific laws preventing it - but a healthy and safety assessment is suggested before allowing it. Some high level discussion [here](http://www.hrreview.co.uk/hr-news/wellbeing-news/how-safe-is-it-to-bring-your-pet-to-work/53736).

Comment: Do remember that just because an owner of a dog considers their dog to be "well-behaved" does not mean that everyone else in the office will see the same thing.  Everyone has their own definition of what "well-behaved" is.   One question that one should ask themselves before bringing a pet to work with them, even if there are laws saying you can:  Will my co-workers be accepting, will this possibly affect the office environment, are any employees possibly allergic to *insert animal here*..things of that nature.  Also:  Is it professional to bring my pet to work?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.contactlaw.co.uk/277-nolink-uk/area-of-law-faqs/employment-law-faqs/workplace-information-faqs/3765-faqs-bringing-pets-to-work.html

That doesn't cite a source, but there are similar results that echo the advice on this link. Anecdotally, a guy at my office sometimes brings his dog into the office when he has to work over night. The dog is well behaved and you wouldn't know it was there.

I can't find a law that prevents this but it's important to note this doesn't make it 'right'. You would still need to seek permission from your employer. I'm not a lawyer but I think your first step would be to broach the subject with them rather than a lawyer as a first step.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few things to consider.

- Health and safety: Will the dog bite? Are there any allergies, staff
  and clients alike?
- Working environment: Will this have a negative impact on any staff?
  Will this impact be considered in their performance reviews?
- General other: Is this an office? Is there a physical product? Will
  there be issues with warranties, etc?

I've worked in a couple of places with office dogs. They tend to make the day go by much easier.

Comment: this doesn't even attempt to address the question asked [as it appears after the edit in rev 3](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/81854/revisions): "Does the UK have laws that would prevent bringing pets to work (with permission)?"

Comment: Actually, @gnat, although I don't cite specific acts of specific laws, the applicable laws will be in the areas that I mentioned: H&S, employment, tort.